# How to call SharePoint list form, from other SharePoint list form, on clicking Next button?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have two lists, List A and List B, now I need to call "List B form" from "List A form" on clicking "next button of List A form".
Its like series of different forms of lists, i need to call one after other.
These list are under same site. So it will be like a wizard that will run on different lists.

Forms can be of InfoPath or SharePoint default forms, i hope there will be no issue in this regard. I'm Using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: when the user clicks "next", you want to actually save the list item, and then redirect, right? What if the default Save button did this redirect instead? What version of SharePoint? Are your new item forms launching in a dialog or full-page?

Comment: im using sharepoint 2010, and yes i want to save the data of first list then wants to redirect to next form, and my form should be in dialog box not full page.

Comment: Could you use a custom form that uses JSOM? Is this form only used in specific instances, or is it going to be the default method for adding new items to List A when users click "new" on the lists item tool bar?

Comment: Robert's custom form/JSOM suggestion is a valid approach, and you can build a really cool user experience that way. It's fairly advanced technically though, especially if you have complex field types on the forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really common use case and I've been asked numerous times by clients to implement this type of functionality.  This can be done through SharePoint designer and a fair bit of JavaScript. It involves a number of steps:

1. Create a link that executes a JavaScript function that you will write in step 2. Your users will click this instead of the default "Add new Item" links.  Alternately you can hijack the event handler for the New Item link and ribbon button, but just creating a new link is a simpler approach.
2. Define a JavaScript function that uses the Dialog Framework to open your new item form.  Also define a callback to handle what happens when that form is closed. Here is where you'll call another function that will open List B's new form.

Something like this:

```
function OpenListAForm(){
  var options =
  {
    url: L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Lists/List A/NewForm.aspx",
    dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, newFormClosedCallback)
  };
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

and the callback...

```
function newFormClosedCallback(result, target) {
    if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        //do you need the ID of the item you just created?
        OpenListBNewForm();
    }
    if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
        //handle the case where the user clicked cancel. Probably do nothing
    }
}
```

Usually in these cases there is a lookup on List B that points back to List A, and users expect to have that lookup already selected in List B's form. But that's probably a separate question.